# Image editor/creator similiar to Adobe Flash

Tags: adobe-flash, image-editing

Is there an image editor with similar editing functionality to Adobe Flash's?

I like the way that you can specify the precise coordinates and dimension of every object.
I don't need the ability to work with multiple frames or being able to run code.

Comment: Similar in what way? Must it produce SWFs?

Comment: @Gnubie I would like to be able to specify the precise coordinates and dimension of every object. And no, just image files, preferable PNGs.